# Increment a char field

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a table that is in the format

```
Muser  char(27), null
privilege char(15), null
Flags (smallint, null)

MUSER Privilege Flags
1     ALL       0
1     ASSIGNEE  0
1     ALL       0
etc
```

I want to increment the char column MUSER by value of 1
Currently every record in MUSER has a value of 1

After the update increment MUSER should read

```
1
2
3
etc
```

How would I do this as I cant get my head around it - would appreciate the tsql if possible.

Comment: What is the plan after you have set every value in the table? Are you planning on changing it to an INT NOT NULL IDENTITY? If not, how do you intend to handle new rows in future? Leave them at 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way, use a CTE and `row_number()` function:

```
with toupdate (
      select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by (select NULL)) as seqnum
      from t
     )
update toupdate
    set Muser = cast(seqnum as varchar(255));
```

You don't specify an ordering.  The `order by (select NULL)` chooses an arbitrary ordering.

And, why are you storing integers in a character field?  Something seems amiss with your data structure.

Comment: If the number is 999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,998 I see problems :)

Comment: Ah long story - someone here meddling trying to sanitise the column for export offsite - updated the table to there valuse - but the offsite company needs the field incremental...

Comment: Invalid object name 't' ??  with cte_toupdate
AS
 (select t.*,row_number() over (order by (select NULL)) as seqnum from t)
update cte_toupdate
    set Muser = cast(seqnum as varchar(255));

Comment: @MoOriginal you're meant to replace references to `t` in this answer with the name of your table - as you haven't supplied it. Gordon used `t` as a placeholder table name.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way as well:

**[Fiddle example here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e9ecf/3)**

```
declare @id char(27) 
update mytable set @id = muser = convert(int,isnull(@id,'0')) + 1 


--Results
| MUSER                       | PRIVILEGE       | FLAGS |
---------------------------------------------------------
| 1                           | ALL             |     0 |
| 2                           | ASSIGNEE        |     0 |
| 3                           | ALL             |     0 |
```